# ASP MVC: Why aren't my internal classes visible from my Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<ul>
    <li><% Html.ActionLink(StringHelper.TryGetLocalString("Something"),
             "Blah", "Blah"); %></li>
</ul>
```

I had to make the StringHelper class above public before I could see it from within my partial view.

**Why??**

(side note: resolving to local string will be done in my controller not in the view (layout) but its a good quick example).

Thanks for you help, Luke

Comment: As soon as I've posted this question I've began to wonder if my assumption that all code is compiled and placed in the same assembly is wrong.

Comment: Aye aye capitan. Views are, by default, not compiled with MVC 1 or 2 when debugging. There are ways to get them to compile, if it is really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the StringHelper is most likely not compiled into the same DLL as the rest of the code for the MVC site, it doesn't have access to internal things.

This will be the case when you have controllers, views, etc, as the default MVC website setup (and how it works when debugging) is to compile the regular code down to a DLL, then compile the pages/views separately. This also happens when you have "Updatability" setup when you publish the website.

Comment: So what's the solution? I don't really want to make all my classes public

Comment: In the example in the question, the answer was to move the logic into the controller or make a public extension method on string "Hello".TryToLocalise() which then calls down to the StringHelper.

Comment: @VincePanuccio only the method that is needed by the view needs to be public. Like Luke's example. Still a bit off considering they are in the same project. You could also try having the views in a DLL that you can reference via something like: http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/

Answer (score 2):

Views (or aspx/ascx files) in ASP.NET are compiled when the web server loads the application. This probably means that they are in another assembly and your classes are internal... you get the point.